# Webpack uninstall not working properly

Tags: npm, webpack

I decided to remove webpack from one of my react projects as dependencies slow down performance and I wasn't really using it. I tried npm uninstall -g webpack, npm uninstall webpack, npm uninstall webpack webpack-cli, npm remove webpack, etc. I ran npm start after each of these commands to start working on my app again and every time I got the same exact answer: "Error: cannot find module 'webpack'". It seems to be based in the internal loader for the react-scripts but I don't know how to edit that. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. Note: I did check my dependencies and webpack is not there in either the main or developer dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said something about react-scripts, i'll assume you are using CRA.

The whole build process is inside the [react-scripts](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/package.json#L70) package, which means that you would need to NOT use react-scrips on you start and build scripts. If you get rid of react-scripts you might be able to get away with webpack.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I avoided the script and it ran with no issues